# QUERY to merge the names of two regions and sum the number of their occurrences

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have an array with states/regions in the UK. Some regions occur more than once in this list, so I have performed a `COUNTIF` to determine the number of times that each one occur.

Now I need to run a `QUERY` to list top 5 regions.

Generally, most occurrences are for the London area.

The issue is that in the regions there are 2 states that refer to the Greater London area - London and Greater London.

These two I need to merge and sum their values.
There needs to be only one region - Greater London, and its value needs to hold the sum of London and Greater London.

This is the dataset I have:

```
+----------------+-------+
| State/Province | count |
+----------------+-------+
| Hampshire      | 1     |
+----------------+-------+
| Kent           | 2     |
+----------------+-------+
| West Lothian   | 3     |
+----------------+-------+
| London         | 4     |
+----------------+-------+
| Greater London | 5     |
+----------------+-------+
| Cheshire       | 6     |
+----------------+-------+
```

I have managed to put together this `QUERY` so far:

`=QUERY(A1:B,"select A, max(B) group by A order by max(B) desc limit 5 label max(B) 'Number of occurrences'",1)`

That gives me this output:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| State/Province | Number of occurrences |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Cheshire       | 6                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Greater London | 5                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| London         | 4                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| West Lothian   | 3                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Kent           | 2                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

What I need is the Greater London and London entries to be merged under the name Greater London and their numbers of occurrences to be summed, providing this result:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| State/Province | Number of occurrences |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Greater London | 9                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Cheshire       | 6                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| West Lothian   | 3                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Kent           | 2                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Hampshire      | 1                     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

***Apologies for not sharing a sheet, but I have security restrictions that are not allowing me to share any link to sheet outside the firm.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
 {SUBSTITUTE(IF(A1:A="London","♥",A1:A),"♥","Greater London"),B1:B}),
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"),
 "select Col1, max(Col2) 
  group by Col1 
  order by max(Col2) desc 
  limit 5 
  label max(Col2)'Number of occurrences'",1)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF((A1:A="London")+(A1:A="London2")+(A1:A="London3"),
 "♥",A1:A),"♥","Greater London")),
 "select Col1, count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null and not Col1 = '#N/A'
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1) 'Number of occurrences'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @playr0 Great work! Does the job correctly. I'd like to ask, how can I implement another column as s condition?
What I am thinking of is to limit the `COUNT` to the records that have `1` in the additional column?...

Comment: Something of such, but with the `ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IF(` part implied for both queries in the following: `={Query({Report_dataRange},"Select Col24, Count(Col24) where Col27 = 1 group by Col24 order by Count(Col24) desc limit 5 label count(Col24) ''",0),
  QUERY({Report_dataRange},"Select        Count(Col24)                 group by Col24 order by Count(Col24) desc limit 5 label count(Col24) ''",0)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF((QUERY(A1:B,"where B=1")="London")+
    (QUERY(A1:B,"where B=1")="London2")+
    (QUERY(A1:B,"where B=1")="London3"),
 "♥",QUERY(A1:B,"where B=1")),"♥","Greater London")),
 "select Col1, count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not NULL and not Col1 = '#N/A'
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1) 'Number of occurrences'", 1)
```

[image: 0]